# CSS Class Selectors

Tags: css, xhtml

I'm more of a server side person, so for the css sample below, I understand what the first 2 groups of css selectors are doing.

I don't understand the 3rd.

Given that the home class only occurs once in the html, it seems redundant to specify the class twice.  This comes from the site clearleft.com.  What is the purpose of the last group of selectors?

Thanks in advance.

```
<ol id="nav">
    <li class="home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
</ol>

#nav li.home a,
#nav li.home a:link,
#nav li.home a:visited {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

#nav li.home a:hover,
#nav li.home a:focus,
#nav li.home a:active {
    background-position: 0 -119px;
}

.home #nav li.home a,
.home #nav li.home a:link,
.home #nav li.home a:visited,
.home #nav li.home a:hover, 
.home #nav li.home a:focus,
.home #nav li.home a:active {
    background-position: 0 -238px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of you are right, I didn't post the complete html.  I figured out the reason.  There is a parent div tag with the home class name.  It's used to highlight the selected menu item for a given page.  Sorry for the confusion, but the responses did lead me to check pages other than the one I was using, which lead me to the answer.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

```
.home #nav li.home a
```

It stands for:
The `anchor` within the `list-item` which is of class `home` within the `nav` id, which is again inside of class `home`. I think the CSS is wrong.

Comment: Or somewhere in the code it has the second combiunation, any way +1 for the wrong.

Comment: your explanation is wrong there. The #nav element is *within* an element of class home, it doesn't *have* that class.

Comment: Thank you, nickf. I have: s/again of/again inside of/ in my post. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

The last set will only match 'a' element that is a child of a home class element, child of the nav id element home of a li element with home class.

Why would you need it:

1) There could be another rule's selector that overrides the #nav li.home a rule in certain cases. Eg

```
.home #nav li.home a  
vs
.interior #nav li.home a
```

2) You could also have another selector that is less descriminating. Eg

```
#nav li a
```

Above assumes that there is other html (perhaps on other pages) that all use the same css file.

Edit -- Another thought: Since the background positions of the three sets of selectors is different, my guess that they're handling the #nav cases in three different page styles. And the selectors are needed so the rules only work on the appropriate pages.

Comment: Isn't your #1 wrong? .home appears inside #nav in the html code in the question, not the other way around..

Comment: I agree with you about the html code you're showing. If the html shown is the only time #nav is used in any page. It could also be that the pages are being dynamically generated and sometimes the nav element is in a different context. And it could also be css cruft from prior versions of the site. Main thing to note (as you know) is that a class can appear multiple times in html. But ids need to be unique per page (but not per site).

Answer (score 1):

If you set `<body class="home">` or `<div class="home">` as a parent container of the menu, you can control the look of the menu on that page or in that div.

```
<div class="home">
  <ol id="nav">
     <li class="home">
           <a href="/">Home</a>
     </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

I was thinking that it could be applied to cascading style submenu's; eg

```
<ol id="nav">
  <li class="home">
        <a href="/">Home</a>
        <ul id="nav">
           <li><a href="#">SubNav</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Though that doesn't quite make sense, more becuase id `#nav` is used twice, when id's can only be used once per document.

Answer (score 1):

This group of selectors would select

1. links (<a> elements) in any of the states: visited, hover, focus,.....
2. where (1) is a descendant element of an `li` element with `class=home`
3. where (2) is a descendant element of an an element with `id=nav`
4. where (3) is a descendant element of an an element with `class=home`

Your sample HTML contains no elements that match these conditions, so nothing will be selected.

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time in order to highlight the current page in the menu without adding a class of 'current'. This comes in useful if you e.g. use a php include for the menu. [clearleft's](http://clearleft.com/) navigation looks like this

```
<ol id="nav">
   <li class="home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
   <li class="who-we-are"><a href="/is/">Who we are</a></li>
   <li class="what-we-do"><a href="/does/">What we do</a></li>
   <li class="stuff-we-made"><a href="/made/">Stuff we made</a></li>
   <li class="work-with-us"><a href="/canhelp/">Work with us</a></li>
</ol>
```

And the `body` for the different pages looks like this

```
<body id="index" class="home">
<body id="index" class="who-we-are">
<body id="index" class="what-we-do">
etc.
```

Note - just saw you posted an answer to yourself while I was writing, but I'll still include this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's redundant, its simply wrong. Maybe the result of some css cleanup that ended up lost in the code, or something?

From your html code, the #nav object never appears inside an object of class .home, so the third CSS statement won't match anything.